# How to change default Measured Grid letters (e.g. to E, N) in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules

I want put the letter N and letter E and the end the number of coordinate, for example:

> 105608.00 E

[image]

Comment: This is not a recommended practice because 105608 is a XY coordinate, not a lat long coordinate. And the X/Y axis do usually not follow the meridians and parallels. That being said, it is not possible in ArcGIS from what I know (not for grids, I mean, because it is possible with graticules, which makes sense)

Comment: @radouxju I'm interpreting the question as the OP wants to append E(asting) and N(northing) at the end of projected CRS values. Why do you think lat-long values are involved?

Comment: What I meant is that XY is not exactly the same as WN, so my opinion is that it is not a good practice in most cases. But +1 because the use of style is indeed a way to add the letter (I had never pressed ths button) and this answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can come is to create a measured grid in ArcMap. General steps:

1. Open data frame properties
2. Select the Grids tab
3. Start the Grids & Graticules wizard and follow the steps.
4. Once the grid is created, you can make changes to the style of the grid with the Style button on the Grids tab.
5. Scroll down to the bottom of the list--any of the MGRS or USNG styles will append E or N to the major grid line labels.

Another possibility is to use the Make Grids and Graticules Layer tool in the Cartography Tools toolbox. That uses an xml file to determine the properties of the grid. The existing xml files are in the GridTemplates folder in your ArcGIS install folder. You might be able to use one as a starting point to create the look you want.

NOTE: This is not my area of expertise in ArcMap and there may be other, better solutions.